# Mvc @Html.DisplayFor to return multiplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)*(modelItem => item.PartsPrice)
```

I can display 1 or both item but unable to multiply any easy solution for above situation?

Comment: Use a view model with a property for the calculated value.

Comment: @Natanoel koranski if my answer helpful to you than you can accept my answer also.

Answer (score 8):

Create **Price** property in your modal as shown below than after use of Price property to display multiplication in your view page.

Price property declaration in modal.

```
public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        return Quantity * PartsPrice;
    }
}
```

Display in razor view page as follow.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer cant get it running, This is a  DETAILS view folder with a for loop to display a order, when create a new  Price the Quantity and PartsPrice cannot be found to do the calculatotion, as it is a {get;set}                                                                                         public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        return Quantity * PartsPrice;
    }
}

Comment: BIT MORE CODE,  this is a view folder under Vehicle model which links to JobDetails called Details                                                                                                          @foreach (var item in Model.JobDetails)
    {
       
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)*(modelItem => item.PartsPrice)

Answer (score 2):

You can not calculate like that. You can calculate in model, otherwise if you want to calculate the values in view, you can try the following

```
@{
    var result = Model.Quantity * Model.PartsPrice; // Calculate the price
    <span>@result</span>
}
```

@result will display the calculated value

if suppose the model is collection then, use foreach loop

```
@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var result = item.Quantity * item.PartsPrice; // Calculate the price
        <span>@result</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: The second code blocked worked perfectly for me inside of a foreach loop. This is very good.